# Crowdsource feedback for research articles

Tags: grammar, feedback, proofreading, writing-groups

Are there crowdsourced feedback platforms, or does somebody know where I can find somebody that does not ask a lot of money for checking some research articles that I have written for mistakes in grammar, spelling, punctuation etc  so that I can deliver this file as a pdf or tex and have it commented on or corrected. (I know there are organisations that can do this but this is a little bit expensive)

Comment: What is your definition of *expensive*? How much money would you be willing to pay?

Comment: Is Fiverr (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiverr ) an option?  It's not exactly crowdsourced, but a low-cost proofread can probably happen through them.     I don't know if there's any way for individuals to get tasks up on Amazon's Mechanical Turk (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Mechanical_Turk ), but that sounds *most* like what you want - distributed crowdsourced work?

Comment: commenting my comment -- I have no experience with either, but I am contemplating using Fiverr for audio editing.

Comment: @April I am familiar with M-Turk, but is it possible to get there feedback on a task like mine?

Comment: @Xilpex not much at most $5 for per research article.

Comment: M-Turk -- not sure if they accept small jobs or if it's only huge things with thousands of pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your **only** requirements are to check mistakes in *grammar*, *spelling* and *punctuation*, then you can use grammar checking tools(or websites) such as https://www.grammarly.com
I have used it personally and it's easy and efficient to use and free of cost.

But, if you want other **people** to give feedback on your content, https://www.kalaage.net can be a helpful website for you. Proofreading of your content will be done by the users at this website(who will get paid by the website itself for this task)

P.S. This is not an advertisement. I don't work for these sites. I have personally used the first website but I don't know much about the second site. I just mentioned because its one of the sites which **can** be used for crowdsourced proofreading (I can't guarantee you for the quality of proofreading)

Comment: Do you have any experience with the site you mentioned? How was the quality of the proofreading? What do users have to pay for the use of this service? Currently you don't state whether or not you are affilitated with the site and there rarely is something for free, so I am asking these questions to make sure this is not some kind of marketing and so that future readers will know what to expect when they click on that link you provided.

Comment: @Secespitus This is not an advertisement. I don't work for these companies. I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks! Just a tip for the future: we get lots of spam at times, so it's a good idea to mention how you know the company and what you think/know about their pricing.

Comment: @Secespitus I'll take care of that in future. Thank you